# Problema con formatos

Tags: python, binance

Amigos les saludo desde México, esperando que alguien me pueda ayudar, tengo una función que va y revisa los precios de un simbolo, pero me los devuelve siempre en formato de notación científica, el problema es que cuando quiero regresar ese mismo valor, no acepta la notación científica, ya intenté con format y no valió, adjunto el código

```
def comprarsell(simbolo, presicion, lacantidad):
    cantidad=float(lacantidad)
    miorden=[]
    while True:
        try:
            cantidad=format(cantidad,"f")
            miorden = cliente.order_market_sell(symbol=simbolo, quantity=cantidad)
            break
        except BinanceAPIException as error:
            print(error.code)
            if error.code==-2010:
                #vamos a reducir una a una la cantidad
                cantidad=float(cantidad)-(1/10**presicion)
                cantidad=round(cantidad,presicion)
            else:
                print(error.message,error.code)
                break
    return miorden
```

La idea es la siguiente, el lote debe llevar una cantidad exacta, así que si arroja el codigo -2010 (lote inexacto) reduce según la presición, fracción a fracción, pero haga lo haga (por ejemplo arriba puse format(cantidad,"f") que se supone que forza a un float, me sigue devolviendo notación científica y la parte del servidor no reconoce ese formato, alguna sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Tiene que ser número? ¿No acepta cadenas (string)?

Comment: Mmm... nop, `format(cantidad, "f")`  te devuelve un string

Comment: la notación científica es solo una forma amigable en que la maquina te muestra el número, luego sigue siendo un numero largo

Comment: Christian tienes razón, format devuelve str y ese era error jejejeje, mil gracias por tu aporte, no se como se dan estrellas o felicitaciones pero 5 estrellas para ti